# C# Second HttpWebRequest after 401 has a delay of 2-3 mins

Tags: c#, httprequest, wireshark

I have the problem that my first HttpWebRequest gets a 401 back.
Here the credentials are missing in the Http Request Header.

But the second request is sent after 2-3 min.

The default timeout for the request is 100 seconds and in this time I get a timeout exception.

Only when I increase the timeout to 400 seconds, the request works successfully.

Here is my code:

```
private HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData)
{
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
    }

    // Set up the request properties.
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = contentType;
    request.UserAgent = userAgent;
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
    request.Timeout = 400000;

    request.Proxy = null;

    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    if (null != mCredentials)
    {
        request.Credentials = mCredentials;
    }

    Log.Info("Log", $"Part 5, {request.Proxy}");
    Log.Info("Log", $"Part 6 {request.Credentials}, {request.Address}, {request.Timeout}");

    // Send the form data to the request.
    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        Log.Info("Log", $"Part 7, {request.Address}, {request.Timeout}");

        requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);

        Log.Info("Log", $"Part 8, {request.Address}, {request.Timeout}");

        requestStream.Close();
        Log.Info("Log", $"Part 9");

    }
    Log.Info("Log", $"Part 10");

    var a = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    Log.Info("Log", $"Part 11 {a.StatusCode}, {a.StatusDescription}, {a.Headers}");

    return null;
}
```

I just added a few log lines to recognize the consequence in the logs as well:

Here are the logs of it:

```
2022-03-18 13:03:25.494 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 5, 

2022-03-18 13:03:25.494 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 6 System.Net.NetworkCredential,**********, 400000

2022-03-18 13:03:25.497 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 7, ***************, 400000

2022-03-18 13:03:25.547 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 8, ***************, 400000

2022-03-18 13:03:25.547 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 9

2022-03-18 13:03:25.547 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 10

2022-03-18 13:06:14.246 INFO [T] App: [17] Log - Part 11 OK, OK, Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

And here also an export from wireshark:
[image: Wireshark]

Comment: What if you cURL it from a cmd or from a browser?

Comment: Maybe the remote server is just being slow...

Comment: Are you using a database?  What type of database?  Queries of database can take a long time to complete.

Comment: I don't know the inner structure of the web service. I can perform the same stuff from the browser and from there it doesn't come to this problem